# twitter follow button not appearing in localhost setup

Tags: javascript, twitter

I went to twitter development tools site [here](https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons#follow), and I setup the button code for the follow intent.

[image: twitter follow screenshot]

So I posted the following code to my site:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/example" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow me on Twitter!</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```

But on my localhost:8000 for Jekyll all I see is this:

[image: just the link]

The button does not appear. Any ideas? I disabled all adblocks and also tried in different browsers. Perhaps it is that it's only localhost now? I'm just wondering how I can debug it in that case (and why that is the case, if so).

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a same-origin error in the browser's console?

Comment: to add on, this doesn't show up once published live at a public IP address either.

Comment: Do you think it has something to do with Jekyll?

Comment: No, it just outputs HTML/CSS (snippet above) which doesn't cause the twitter button to appear. no adblockers either.

Answer (score -1):

Twitter button always appears in localhost or even if u create a normal html file and embed the code and run it locally. However there are 3 scenarios and that goes for almost all the social buttons.

> 1) Make sure that you test it on a running web server.
>
> 2) Check on other browsers before concluding the inefficiency of your code.
>
> 3)Secondly code for 'Twitter' button should be in the index file rather than any other partials. It will certainly work and that goes for almost all the other social buttons.